# ElasticSearch: Return all elements between two events

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a lot of log messages in one ElasticSearch index. 
These log messages containing two special messages. One start message and one end message (simply having a field with the value 'START' and 'STOP').

Can I create a query in ElasticSearch that returns all logs in that index between these two messages?

Thanks for your help.

Update:

Here an example that shows simplified how my data look like:

```
PUT log
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "timestamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "epoch_millis"
        },
        "msg": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT log/_doc/1
{
    "timestamp": 1000,
    "msg" : "TO_EARLY"
}


PUT log/_doc/2
{
    "timestamp": 2000,
    "msg" : "START"
}

PUT log/_doc/3
{
    "timestamp": 3000,
    "msg" : "Hello, World!"
}

PUT log/_doc/4
{
    "timestamp": 4000,
    "msg" : "STOP"
}

PUT log/_doc/5
{
    "timestamp": 5000,
    "msg" : "TO_LATE"
}
```

So my question is: How does the query looks like to get the message between the START and the STOP message?

Comment: So you means returns all documents in a index between 2 documents the first getting a START tag a the second a STOP tag. Use the _timestamps field (enabled it), or increment an id should work.

Comment: But how can I do that in one query?

Comment: It s hard to give acurante response without more information about your data but it s possible to do it using a script filter. On the script get the range you are looking about by searching the START and STOP tags.

Comment: I updated my question with a simplified example. Would be great if you could explain me your solution with this example. Thx!